# Can't mapping type inherit from List<T>

Tags: c#, automapper

There are two types inherit List, and I want to use AutoMapper maping it.
map result is empty when mapping Type inherit from List

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap(typeof(ListA<>), typeof(ListB<>));
        });

        ListA<string> a = new ListA<string>()
        {
            Name = "A"
        };
        a.Add("AAAA");


        var b = Mapper.Map<ListB<string>>(a);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}


class ListA<T> : List<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class ListB<T> : List<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [Something to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html